# Why is `filterM + mapM_` so much slower than `mapM_ + when`, with large lists?

Tags: performance, haskell, optimization, monads, io-monad

I don't know very much about how Haskell optimization works internally but I've been using filters quite much hoping that they are optimized into something equivalent to a simple if in C++. For example

```
mapM_ print $ filter (\n -> n `mod` 2 == 0) [0..10]
```

will compile into equivalent of

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    if (i%2 == 0)
        printf("%d\n", i);
```

With long lists (10 000 000 elements) it seems to be true for a basic `filter` but there is a huge difference if I use the monadic `filterM`. I wrote a piece of code for this speed testing and it's obvious that the usage of `filterM` lasts much longer (250x) than a more imperative approach using `when`.

```
import Data.Array.IO
import Control.Monad
import System.CPUTime

main :: IO ()
main = do
  start <- getCPUTime
  arr <- newArray (0, 100) 0 :: IO (IOUArray Int Int)
  let
    okSimple i =
      i < 100

    ok i = do
      return $ i < 100
    -- -- of course we don't need IO for a simple i < 100
    -- -- but my goal is to ask for the contents of the array, e.g.
    -- ok i = do
    --   current <- readArray arr (i `mod` 101)
    --   return$ i `mod` 37 > current `mod` 37
    
    write :: Int -> IO ()
    write i =
      writeArray arr (i `mod` 101) i

    writeIfOkSimple :: Int -> IO ()
    writeIfOkSimple i =
      when (okSimple i) $ write i

    writeIfOk :: Int -> IO ()
    writeIfOk i =
      ok i >>= (\isOk -> when isOk $ write i)

  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  ---- these four methods have approximately same execution time ----
  ---- (but the last one is executed on 250 times shorter list)  ----
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- mapM_ write$ filter okSimple [0..10000000*250] -- t = 20.694
  -- mapM_ writeIfOkSimple [0..10000000*250]        -- t = 20.698
  -- mapM_ writeIfOk [0..10000000*250]              -- t = 20.669
  filterM ok [0..10000000] >>= mapM_ write          -- t = 17.200

  -- evaluate array
  elems <- getElems arr
  print $ sum elems

  end <- getCPUTime
  print $ fromIntegral (end - start) / (10^12)
```

My question is: shouldn't both approaches (using `writeIfOk` / using `filterM ok` and `write`) compile into the same code (iterate list, ask for condition, write data)? If not, can I do something (rewrite code, add compilation flags, use inline pragma or something) to make them computationally equivalent or should I always use `when` when performance is critical?

Comment: Your last test only works up to `10000000`, not `10000000*250`?

Comment: The fact that `filterM` takes more time, is not that suprisingly: it is not subject to *list fusion*, and furthermore it will result in a lot of wrapping and unwrapping in `IO` objects, if not optimized effectively.

Comment: In the last test I used 250x shorter list achieving approximately the same computation time as in the previous tests (I wanted to express it is 250x slower). Thanks, I'm going to have a look at list fusion and IO wrapping/unwrapping.

Comment: You are effectively asking the compiler to spot that `ok` has no side effects despite the `IO` in its signature, and optimize for that case enabling streaming. The compiler might do that, using sufficiently advanced static analysis, but current GHC won't. I guess this scenario is not that common, since Haskell programmers tend to not mark as `IO` something that's actually pure, and prefer to use non-`IO` routines when possible.

Comment: Yes, this is just a minimallistic example of the `ok` function (I wanted to make the test less biased). In practice I use `readArray` in the `ok` function to ask whether the current value is 0.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, list fusion is irrelevant here.

Comment: @chi, that would also require some really fancy termination analysis to see that the `filterM` will always complete successfully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boiling this question down to its essence, your asking about the difference between

```
f (filter g xs)
```

and

```
f =<< filterM (pure . g) xs
```

This basically comes down to laziness. `filter g xs` produces its result incrementally as it's demanded, only walking `xs` far enough to find the next element of the result. `filterM` is defined something like this:

```
filterM _p [] = pure []
filterM p (x : xs)
  = liftA2 (\q r -> if q then x : r else r)
           (p x)
           (filterM p xs)
```

Since `IO` is a "strict" applicative, this will not produce anything at all until it's walked the whole list, accumulating the `p x` results in memory.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy this explanation. If it cost 50% more, or possibly even 300% more, I might be able to... but 25000% just for putting the whole list in memory?

Comment: @DanielWagner, totally! The GC cost will go through the roof.

Comment: @DanielWagner, cache misses will also go way up.

Comment: Remember that building a big structure takes O(n^2) or so GC time.

Comment: is it quadratic because there's some increment it goes by, internally? and so, it seems some sort of compilation flag could exist to allow us increase that increment so that  the speed would improve drastically? is there such a flag?

Comment: Huh! I had never thought of that (O(n^2) GC time to store it, O(n) to traverse and discard it), but it does make sense.

Comment: @WillNess It is quadratic because a single GC takes time proportional to the amount of live data, and the number of GCs you need to do is proportional to the size of the data structure being built. If you are throwing away the structure as you build it, "the amount of live data" is O(1); but if you must keep it all, "the amount of live data" is O(n).

Comment: @DanielWagner I was thinking along the lines of there's some amount of allocations that triggers the GC maybe? this threshold could in theory be increased, so there'd be fewer GCs, and since it's quadratic, it could make it faster.

Comment: @WillNess, there are various knobs to tweak with RTS options. But that's a blunt instrument; it affects the whole program.

Comment: @WillNess, I guess the cheapest knob for this purpose is the initial heap size, whatever that knob is called. It won't have such wild impacts as, say, tweaking the nursery size.

Comment: searching for "GHC nursery" brings up various stuff, thanks for the reference. :)

Comment: @DanielWagner, I'm starting to wonder if it's more like O(n sqrt n) or something. It depends on how the heap grows. But it's definitely super-linear, and it definitely can make things very, very slow.

Comment: Thanks, now I will have a better understanding of what happens behind the scenes. Just to address the discussion I've made some tests with different list lengths and the results seem to be quite linear (list length: CPU duration (real-time duration);): 100 000 000: 224.227 (21.4s); 10 000 000: 17.406 (1.73); 1 000 000: 1.930 (0.19); 100 000: 0.193 (0.02); 10 000: 0.0005 (0.0004) - here I probably reached the initial heap size; 1 000 000 000: my computer freezed on caching - proof that the is really fully allocated.

Comment: But I think we would really go into the depths of hardware optimization etc. analyzing this... For example the test with [0..10 000 000] lasted twice as long before restarting the computer than after restarting (because of RAM fragmentation I guess...)